# django:How to use "objects.all()" and "for" in async

Tags: python, django, python-asyncio

I want to access the information of the model periodically using asyncio and threading.

After fetching the model data with objects.all() in the async coroutine, an error occurs when running the for loop.

```
You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.
```

---code---

```
[task.py]
asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(chat.handle(), loop.LOOP)
```

```
[chat.py]
async def handle():
    while True:
        users = user.objects.all()
        for user in users:
            print(user.user_id)
        await asyncio.sleep(60)
```

---Details---

```
[Website/loop.py]
import asyncio


LOOP = None

def run_loop():
    global LOOP
    LOOP = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    LOOP.run_forever()
```

```
[Website/__init__.py]
from Monitoring import loop
import threading
import sys


threading.Thread(target=loop.run_loop).start()
```

When you access the test page, check() in task.py will work.

```
[Monitoring/task.py]]
import asyncio
from Monitoring import chat
from Website import loop


def check():    
    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(chat.handle(), loop.LOOP)
```

```
[Monitoring/chat.py]
import asyncio
from Monitoring.models import User


async def handle():
    while True:
        users = User.objects.all()
        for user in users:
            print(user.user_id)
        await asyncio.sleep(60)
```

Comment: _Why_ do you want to mix and match asyncio _and_ threading here? In any case, the error stems from the fact that [the Django ORM doesn't support async yet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/async/#).

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible with the current version. I understand.